# eth_getStorageAt does not work with EIP-1967 standard proxy storage slots

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm running an ethereum side-chain node that is based on the Infura API.

I'm trying to read a EIP-1967 proxy storage slot with an eth_getStorageAt RPC call. But the call only returns "hex string has length 64, want 40 for common.Address". However all proxy storage addresses are of length 64.

The OpenZeppelin (an alternative to Infura) API documentation writes:

> To get this value clients can read directly from the storage slot
> shown below (specified by EIP1967) using the eth_getStorageAt RPC
> call.
>
> 0xb53127684a568b3173ae13b9f8a6016e243e63b6e8ee1178d6a717850b5d6103

It looks like it's only a problem with Infura. Is there a way to fix this or are there any alternative ways to retrieve storage data from an ethereum side-chain?

Comment: You may have inverted `eth_getStorageAt`'s arguments. First the address, then the storage slot.

Comment: @RiccardoS I did it exactly as in the documentation. First argument the storage address, second argument `0`

Comment: The first argument is the contract address, not storage address

Comment: @RiccardoS So the storage address is used as the index parameter?

Comment: Yeah, the second argument. I would use `eth_getStorageAt(proxyContractAddress, 0xb53127684a568b3173ae13b9f8a6016e243e63b6e8ee1178d6a717850b5d6103)`

Comment: @RiccardoS I tried it but it only returns '0x0...0'. It's supposed to return the implementation address. The storage slot is listed in the decompiled byte code of the contract, as well as the default functions like implementation() or _fallback(), so it's definitely used according to the standard.